# Mouseup event not firing in D3 zooming

Tags: d3.js

```js
d3
  .select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', 300)
  .attr('height', 300)
  .on('mousedown', () => {
      console.log('mousedown trigger')
  })
  .on('mouseup', () => {
      console.log('mouseup trigger')
  })
  .call(
      d3.zoom()
          .scaleExtent([0.1, 10])
          .on('zoom', function() {
              console.log('zoom trigger')
          })
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
```

platform: macos 10.13.2 chrome 67.0.3396.99

My code like this, and in the latest d3 version , 5.5.0, the mouseup event did not trigger. However, I try the version 3.5.0, everything is ok. what's wrong with that?

Comment: Have a look at the API: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#api-reference. It says `mouseup --> Default prevented: Yes`.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Gerardo Furtado in the comment, mouseup event is prevented by d3-zoom (since d3.v4). However the `click` event will be triggered if registered before the zoom behavior as in your example.

See discussion https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/66.

Comment: According to my tests it doesn't matter whether you register the click before or after registering the zoom the effect is the same. Also, if there occurs a mousemove event, then click will not be fired either. As such you propose no solution.